# Sparql Preventing Looping queries (MarkLogic)

Tags: sparql, marklogic

Hi i am currently trying to do some analysis with SPARQL in Marklogic and would like to know if it is possible to prevent Looping queries? To explain the reason for knowing this we will use the following Data Model

[image]

Suppose I start from A and most importantly I would like to find all nodes between A and G. Upon running the following query in sparql

```
node_A </link>* x
y </link>* node_G
x </link> y
```

I will not be able to get every single nodes between them as I will be missing node B for instance. As I believe MarkLogic Sparql is not up to date (Version 1.1), I will not be able to use the "or" operator to resolve this. Hence the next solution is to make sure every node points to and from one another resulting in a connection such as

```
B=>F
F=>B
```

But doing so will result in looping nodes and hence, I am curious if it is possible to prevent loops in SPARQL Queries. Or if there are any other ways to retrieve all nodes between node X and Node Y please do let me know.

===Update===

Query Used

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

import module namespace sem = "http://marklogic.com/semantics" at "/MarkLogic/semantics.xqy";

let $query := sem:sparql(
'
PREFIX xs: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX cts: <http://marklogic.com/cts#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema/>
PREFIX fn: <http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions#>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>
PREFIX db: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX onto: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns>
PREFIX xdmp: <http://marklogic.com/xdmp#>

SELECT DISTINCT ?x ?y
WHERE{
?x !</path> ?y .
}
',
(),
(),
()
)

return (
$query,
xdmp:elapsed-time(),
"Nil",
"Nil",
"Nil"
)
```

Error Encountered

```
[1.0-ml] XDMP-UNEXPECTED: (err:XPST0003) Unexpected token syntax error, unexpected !
```

Comment: I think at least the most recent two versions of ML (9 & 10) support SPARQL 1.1.

Comment: What do you mean by "between"? There is no path A-\*-B-\*-G

Comment: @BenW I guess when treating the graph as an undirected graph

Comment: Ah I see, I have tried on a different system with ML9 installed and it works. But I noticed that "!" is not supported in MarkLogic 9.0-8.1. Hence, I am curious if it is supported MarkLogic 10?  @wst

Comment: That’s not correct. Simple mapping operator (!) is supported in ML 9.

Comment: Sorry I worded it wrongly, I have checked for sparql 1.1 and it doesn't seem to support "!<path>" expressions. Hence I would like to ask if there is a work around to retrieve all links between two nodes through using something like a wildcard expression "<p>|!<p>". I might have used the "!" expression wrongly so I have updated the question with a simple query and error encountered. @wst

Answer (score 1):

I think you were looking for `|` and `^`. The first is the 'or', the latter allows to follow predicates in reverse direction. The following code seems to run fine for me. I was running ML 10, but pretty sure it works in 9 and 8 just as well:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

xdmp:document-insert('/test/triples.json', object-node {
  "triple": array-node {
    sem:triple(sem:iri("node_A"), sem:iri("/link"), sem:iri("node_C")),
    sem:triple(sem:iri("node_D"), sem:iri("/link"), sem:iri("node_C")),
    sem:triple(sem:iri("node_C"), sem:iri("/link"), sem:iri("node_B")),
    sem:triple(sem:iri("node_C"), sem:iri("/link"), sem:iri("node_E")),
    sem:triple(sem:iri("node_F"), sem:iri("/link"), sem:iri("node_B")),
    sem:triple(sem:iri("node_F"), sem:iri("/link"), sem:iri("node_E")),
    sem:triple(sem:iri("node_F"), sem:iri("/link"), sem:iri("node_G")),
    sem:triple(sem:iri("node_E"), sem:iri("/link"), sem:iri("node_G"))
  }
})

;

sem:sparql("
SELECT DISTINCT ?x
WHERE {
  <node_A> (</link>|^</link>)* ?x.
  ?x (</link>|^</link>)* <node_G>.
  FILTER( !(?x = (<node_A>, <node_G>)) )
}
ORDER BY ?x
")
```

HTH!